# Haskell - Is there a better way of evenly distributing an element over a list

Tags: haskell

Given a matrix like this

```
matrix_table =

[[ 0, 0, 0, 0]
,[ 0, 0, 0, 0]
,[ 0, 0, 0, 0]
,[ 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

and a list `position_list = [2, 3, 2, 10]`

output of a function

```
distribute_ones :: [[Int]] -> [Int] -> [[Int]]
distribute_ones matrix_table position_list
```

should look like this

```
[[ 0, 1, 0, 1] -- 2 '1's in the list
,[ 0, 1, 1, 1] -- 3 '1's in the list
,[ 0, 1, 0, 1] -- 2 '1's in the list
,[ 1, 1, 1, 1] -- Since 10 > 4, all '1's in the list
]
```

---

What I tried:

I generated list of lists, the base matrix with

```
 replicate 4 (replicate 4 0)
```

then divided inner lists with `chunksOf` from `Data.List.Split` library to make cut-outs of `4 - (position_list !! nth)`.

Finally appending and concatenating with `1` like this

```
take 4 . concat . map (1 :)
```

Although I think it's not exactly the best approach.
Is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: Can you please show your full definition for `distribute_ones`? Your use of `!!` is unnecessary. Use `zipWith` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For evenly distributing elements, I recommend Bjorklund's algorithm. Bjorklund's algorithm takes two sequences to merge, and repeatedly:

1. Merges as much of the prefix of the two as it can, taking one from each, then
2. recursively calls itself with the merged elements as one sequence and the leftovers from the longer input as the other sequence.

In code:

```
bjorklund :: [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [a]
bjorklund xs ys = case zipMerge xs ys of
    ([], leftovers) -> concat leftovers
    (merged, leftovers) -> bjorklund merged leftovers

zipMerge :: [[a]] -> [[a]] -> ([[a]], [[a]])
zipMerge [] ys = ([], ys)
zipMerge xs [] = ([], xs)
zipMerge (x:xs) (y:ys) = ((x++y):merged, leftovers) where
    ~(merged, leftovers) = zipMerge xs ys
```

Here's some examples in ghci:

```
> bjorklund (replicate 2 [1]) (replicate 2 [0])
[1,0,1,0]
> bjorklund (replicate 5 [1]) (replicate 8 [0])
[1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0]
```

If you like, you could write a small wrapper that takes just the arguments you care about.

```
ones len numOnes = bjorklund
    (replicate ((-) len numOnes) [0])
    (replicate (min len numOnes) [1])
```

In ghci:

```
> map (ones 4) [2,3,2,10]
[[0,1,0,1],[0,1,1,1],[0,1,0,1],[1,1,1,1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate algorithm to distribute `itemCount` items across `rowLength` cells within a single row.  Initialize `currentCount` to 0.  Then for each cell:

1. Add `itemCount` to `currentCount`.
2. If the new `currentCount` is less than `rowLength`, use the original value of the cell.
3. If the new `currentCount` is at least `rowLength`, subtract `rowLength`, and increment the value of the cell by one.

This algorithm produces the output you expect from the input you provide.

We can write the state required for this as a simple data structure:

```
data Distribution = Distribution { currentCount :: Int
                                 , itemCount    :: Int
                                 , rowLength    :: Int
                                 } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

At each step of the algorithm we need to know whether we're emitting an output (and incrementing the value), and what the next state value will be.

```
nextCount :: Distribution -> Int
nextCount d = currentCount d + itemCount d

willEmit :: Distribution -> Bool
willEmit d = (nextCount d) >= (rowLength d)

nextDistribution :: Distribution -> Distribution
nextDistribution d = d { currentCount = (nextCount d) `mod` (rowLength d) }
```

To keep this as running state, we can package it in [the `State` monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#t:State).  Then we can write the "for each cell" list above as a single function:

```
distributeCell :: Int -> State Distribution Int
distributeCell x = do
  emit <- gets willEmit
  modify nextDistribution
  return $ if emit then x + 1 else x
```

To run this over a whole row, we can use the [`traverse`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.20/base-4.11.1.0/Prelude.html#v:traverse) function from the standard library.  This takes some sort of "container" and a function that maps single values to monadic results, and creates a "container" of the results inside the same monad.  Here the "container" type is `[a]` and the "monad" type is `State Distribution a`, so the specialized type signature of `traverse` is

```
traverse :: (Int -> State Distribution Int)
         -> [Int]
         -> State Distribution [Int]
```

We don't actually care about the final state, we just want the resulting `[Int]` out, which is what [`evalState`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#v:evalState) does.  This would produce:

```
distributeRow :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
distributeRow row count =
  evalState
  (traverse distributeCell row :: State Distribution [Int])
  (Distribution 0 count (length row))
```

Applying this to the whole matrix is a simple application of `zipWith` (given two lists and a function, call the function repeatedly with pairs of items from the two lists, returning the list of results):

```
distributeOnes :: [[Int]] -> [Int] -> [[Int]]
distributeOnes = zipWith distributeRow
```